# How to turn an unknown item from a function's input into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project I'm working on, I'm trying to create a function that can take an inputted list of lists, and add a single random item from each list into a final list. That part works fine. The problem is that I also want to have it so if one of the items in the inputted list isn't defined, rather than causing an error, it converts that item into a string and adds it to the final list.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
import random

ListA = ["Hi", "Hello"]
ListB = ["Bye", "Goodbye", "Farewell"]
ListC = []

def Roll(align):
    for i in align:
        Item = random.choice(i)
        ListC.append(Item)
    print(ListC)
```

I want to input something like this:

```
Roll([ListA, ListB, Thanks])
```

And the output should be something like this:

```
['Hello', 'Farewell', 'Thanks']
```

Ideally I'd rather avoid a solution that requires changing the input. I'm aware that formatting the 'Thanks' into a list for the input fixes the problem, but I want it to be able to decide what is a list and what should just get added on its own.

I've tried using try and except inside the function, but that doesn't seem to work. I assume this is because as soon as the input is given, python immediately notices an item isn't defined and causes an error.

Comment: If you try to call the function with an undefined item, such as in the example `Roll([ListA, ListB, Thanks])`, you will get a `NameError` on the call attempt _before_ even starting the function's execution — so you will need to wrap the ***call to the function*** in a `try`/`except` to handle the exception that occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
if isinstance(item, list):
    # random choice
else:
    # direct append
```